# Generalized form for a matrix $A$ where $\text{Tr}(A^2) = 0$, $\text{Tr}(A) \ne 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a general form for a matrix such that the trace of the matrix is not zero, but the trace of its square is, for any size matrix $n$?

(this was motivated by proving that $\langle A,B\rangle = \text{Tr}(AB)$ is not an inner product for all $M_{n,n}$)

Comment: If $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues counted with algebraic multiplicity, these are the matrices such that $\lambda_1^2+\lambda_2^2+\cdots+\lambda_n^2=0$ and $\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\cdots+\lambda_n\neq 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a $1\times1$ matrix it is not possible to have $\text{Tr} A \neq 0$ and $\text{Tr} A^2 = 0$. For a matrix of size $2$, the following does the job,
$$A_2= \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 \\
  -1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}.$$ For larger $n$ you can use the block matrix
$$ A_n = \left(\begin{array}{c|c}
   A_2 &0\\\hline
   0   & 0
\end{array}\right),$$
i.e., the rest is filled up with zeros.

Comment: Just to note a connection what Fabian wrote with Jonas' comment to the main question: one can identify 2-by-2 matrices of the form `[[a, b], [-b,a]]` with the complex numbers $a+bi$. Then the Trace operator on these matrices corresponds to taking the real part of the complex number. So your problem then reduces to finding a complex number $z$ with non-zero real part such that $z^2$ has zero real part. Fabian's example shows that $1+i$ is one such number.